# Как отправить сообщение с абзацами в боте discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord

попытался отправить в чат в дискорде большое сообщение, делённое абзацами, но Visual Studio Code подчёркивает весь текст как ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот ошибка:

any
',' expected.ts(1005)
View Problem (Alt+F8)
No quick fixes available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`Шаблонные строки`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), чтобы удобно работать со строками, содержащими перенос строки:

> Шаблонные литералы заключены в обратные кавычки (` `) вместо двойных или одинарных.

```
mess.channel.send(`

string1
string2

string3

`)
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо!

Comment: отметьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог